# Why is my custom taghelper crashing?

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In my Razor View I have a  element with my taghelper attribute:

```
<td identity-userRole="@user.Id"></td>
```

Here is my taghelper:

```
using Hrsa.Core.Generic.Model.Lerd.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Hrsa.Core.Web.App.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("td", Attributes = "identity-userRole")]
    public class UserRolesTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private UserManager<AppUser> userManager;
        private RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

        public UserRolesTagHelper(UserManager<AppUser> usermgr,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> rolemgr)
        {
            userManager = usermgr;
            roleManager = rolemgr;
        }

        [HtmlAttributeName("identity-userRole")]
        public string User { get; set; }

        public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context,
            TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            List<string> roles = new List<string>();
            AppUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User);
            if (User != null)
            {
                foreach (var role in await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user))
                {
                    roles.Add(role);
                }
            }

            output.Content.SetContent(roles.Count == 0 ?
                "No Roles" : String.Join(", ", roles));
        }
    }
}
```

I have it registered in _ViewImports.cshtml like this:

```
@addTagHelper Hrsa.Core.Web.App.*, Hrsa.Core.Web.App
```

If I put a break point on the constructor it seems to hit and execute great for each user.
There is a little jumping around because it is async but everything seems to get built up ok.
The user id is passed from the attribute in the HTML and the roles are ready to output to the  at the end of Process in the taghelper.

But then it crashes.

If I run through Cntrl F5, it says:
HTTP ERROR 500.

If I debug then after the third hit for my third user it goes all the way down to:

```
output.Content.SetContent(roles.Count == 0 ?
            "No Roles" : String.Join(", ", roles));
```

and then the execution seems to get swallowed up somewhere.
It just hangs.

Can anyone see anything wrong with this.

Comment: seems like maybe your code mixes User and user, you check if User is null after using it to get user

Comment: User is a string property and it is filled with the UserId from the td attribute:
<td identity-userRole="@user.Id"></td> goes to: "[HtmlAttributeName("identity-userRole")]
        public string User { get; set; }".
 lowercase user is a local declared AppUser : IdentityUser in overridden Process for TagHelper.

Comment: right but why check if User is null after you already used it, should check before using it and seems like you should check if user is null after trying to retrieve it, but instead you check User then

Comment: yep looks like the case of 'Case' management....

Comment: Oh - it should be lower case user null check.  Thanks good catch. But it is still getting built up right.  I don't know why it is giving 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
public override async void Process(TagHelperContext context,
        TagHelperOutput output)
```

to:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context,
        TagHelperOutput output)
```